# Exponential Taylor Series

Tags: c, factorial, taylor-series

This is the code I have so far, which is a little messy since I am still trying to figure out how to set it up, but I cannot figure out how to get the output. This code is supposed to take a Taylor Series polynomial of an exponential, and check the amount of iterations it takes to get the approximation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
/*Prototype for functions used*/
double factorial (int);

int main()
{
   double input = 0;
   double exp_val;
   double delta = 1;
   int f =0;
   int n = 0;
   double taylor;
   int total;
   printf("Plese enter the exponent to check for convergence:\n");
   scanf("%lf", &input);
   exp_val = exp(input);
   printf("  #     Iter      e^X      Sum     Diff\n");
   printf("----   ------   -------   -----  --------");

   while(delta > 0.00001)
   {
      f = factorial(n);
      taylor = ((pow(input,n))/ f);
      delta = (exp_val - taylor);
      printf("%d %f %f %f/n", (n+1), exp_val, taylor, delta);
      n++;
   }
   system("pause");


}

double factorial (int n)
{
  int r = 0;
  int sum = 1;
  int total = 0;
  if (n == 0)
    return total =1;
  else
  {
     for(r; r<n; r++)
     {
        sum = sum * r;
        total = sum + 1;

     }

     return total;
  }

}
```

Comment: Presumably the value you're after is just `n`?

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050980/working-on-code-to-calculate-cosine-with-factorial-sum/22051484#22051484

Comment: Also, your algorithm to compute the Taylor sum is very, very objectionable. Why are you doing all this work again and again and again? Be more lazy! Keep the running term around, and think about how one term differs from the previous one.

Comment: @KerrekSB - As demonstrated in my answer above

Comment: I thought I had an idea of what was going on in the factorial, but I think I made a mistake some where and am not understanding how to fix it. That link is great, but I am confused on how that works with what I have.

Comment: How to compute the factorial of `n` when you know the factorial of `n-1` (just multiple it by `n`! How to compute the value of `x^n` when you have `x^(n-1)` - multiple by `x`! Then just keep the numbers manageable so not overflow. They are like buses and like to be together

Comment: I feel like I am getting closer to the answer, but just need something else to get it to stop putting out junk values

Comment: Your `factorial` function is weird... The `sum` is initially set to be `1`, but provided that the `n != 0`, it will be multiplied by `0` on the first cycle, and will remain as `0` for the rest of the time; which means that the variable `total` will always have the same value of `0 + 1 = 1`, if not still the initial value of `0`. Long story short, the return value will always be `1.0` for that function.

Comment: Should I set it to r+1?

Comment: If the `factorial` was supposed to return the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), then you should make the following changes: **(a)** ditch the `int total = 0;`, **(b)** `return sum;` for both of the returns, **(c)** ditch the `total = sum + 1;`, **(d)** change `sum = sum * r;` into `sum = sum * (r + 1);` or simply `sum *= r + 1;`

Comment: @user3259144 Yes, but tell me, why exactly are you returning `sum + 1` (total) instead of `sum` alone? Factorial isn't defined as `n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... * 1 + 1` it is rather `n * ... * 1` without a `+1`

Comment: I took the total out of the loop, but I need the added one, since it does not add the initial value of the taylor series, which is one. Even with that, I am still getting a flurry of number in the box. Can you figure out what else is wrong with the program

Comment: @user3259144 okay, okay... I'll look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I have fixed it, without changing your approach, except for the parts I really had to. One thing we have to clarify before the code is how Taylor Polynomials are made. It is not the *first term* plus the *nth term*, rather the sum of all terms from the *first term* till the *nth term*. So you definitely have to increase the `taylor` variable by the current *nth term* instead of the other way.

Here's the code, with brief comments in it as the explanation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*Prototype for functions used*/
unsigned long long factorial( int );    // <-- made it return unsigned long long

int main( )
{
    double input = 0;
    double exp_val;
    double delta = 1;
    unsigned long long f = 0;   // <-- changed its type
    int n = 0;
    double taylor = 0;  // <-- initialized with 0
    printf( "Plese enter the exponent to check for convergence:\n" );
    scanf( "%lf", &input );
    exp_val = exp( input );
    printf( " #          e^X            Sum           Diff\n" );        // <-- made some cosmetic changes
    printf( "---      ---------      ---------      ---------\n" );     // <-- added \n

    while ( delta > 0.00001 )
    {
        f = factorial( n );
        taylor += ( ( pow( input, n ) ) / f );  // += instead of =
        delta = ( exp_val - taylor );
        printf( "%2d    %12f   %12f   %12f\n", ( n + 1 ), exp_val, taylor, delta ); // <-- replaced / with \ before the n
        n++;                                                                        // and made some edits to make it look better
    }
    system( "pause" );
    return 0;           // <-- better add this
}

unsigned long long factorial( int n )   // <-- made it return unsigned long long
{
    int r = 0;
    unsigned long long sum = 1; // <-- changed its type
    if ( n == 0 )
        return sum; // <-- this
    else
    {
        for ( r; r<n; r++ )
        {
            sum *= r + 1;   // <-- changed this
        }

        return sum; // <-- and this
    }
}
```

You have to keep in mind that you may not input too high values to it. Anything higher than `input == 4` kind of breaks it, because, you see, even with 4, it can reduce the error `delta` beneath the threshold first only with the 19th cycle. The programme seemingly fails with `n == 5` due to inaccurate calculation of `pow( 5, 21 ) / factorial( 21 )` when `n` reaches `21`:

```
0.000034    // the result this programme finds
0.0000093331055943447405008542892329719 // the result Calculator finds
```

So, yeah... If you want this programme to work with bigger `input` values, you'll need a better approach. Not calculating the *nth term* from scratch and calculating it from the *(n - 1)th term* instead could help until somewhat bigger `input` values, as the others had said.

Comment: Thank you, that makes alot of sense now that I am looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple issue:

1. Change `int r = 0; ... for(r; r<n; r++)` to `int r; ... for(r=1; r<=n; r++)` or `int r = 1; ... for(; r<=n; r++)`
2. Change `printf("%d %f %f %f/n"` to `printf("%d %f %f %f\n"`  Add `\n`
3. Change `"...  --------"` to `"...  --------\n"`
4. Change `delta = (exp_val - taylor);` to `delta = fabs(exp_val - taylor);`
5. Change to `double taylor = 0.0;` Initialize it.
6. Change to `taylor += ((pow(input,n))/ f);`  Note: +=
7. Minor: "Please" not "Plese".
8. Minor: Drop `int total;`