# How do I determine a taylor series ending condition if there are multiple sums?

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements, taylor-series

I'm writing a program that would take two parameters on input: the argument x and the difference e and has to output the result of `f(x) = e^(sinx)`

1. using simple methods from math.h
2. using a sum of a taylor series expansion, with the difference being less than the difference e (from the previous result)

The formula I'm working with is `e^(sinx) = (sum from k=0 to infinity) sin^k(x)/k!`

I then changed the `sin^k(x)` to it's Taylor expansion to the power of k:  `((sum from t=0 to infinity) (-1)^t x^(2t+1)/(2t+1)!)^k`.

The result is a pretty big sum, and I have no idea how to make an end condition to my program. I know, that difference between the values has to be smaller than e, but how do I calculate this if there is a double sum in a loop?

Comment: Taylor series might not be the best to compute such a function. Consider also [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working on code to calculate cosine with factorial sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050980/working-on-code-to-calculate-cosine-with-factorial-sum)

Comment: On each loop iteration, check the difference between the corrent value and the previous value and see if (`fabs`) of that is less than `e`

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, but how do I define how many items from which sum are needed? I mean I have two sums and I need to decide whether to continue summing sine or to get another sum of sine

Comment: @EdHeal those are two completely different questions - my problem is about joining two series together

Comment: @Simon - You should double check - the equations are identical!

Comment: @EdHeal There are no sums inside sums there (he is calculating the taylor series of the sine and cosine, i am trying to calculate the taylor series of the exponential of the sine function)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many terms are needed, you just keep going until the difference is less than `e`