# Pi squared to n digits C++

Tags: c++, pi

I found many similar topics but none of them gives me clear explanation.

I have to write program which calculates Pi squared to n digits using this taylor series:

π^2 = 12 ( 1/1^2 - 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 - 1/4^2 + ... )

I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "How many digits?" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    long double Pi2 = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while( precision is less than n ) {
        if ((i%2) == 1) { 
            Pi2 += 1/pow(i,2); 
            i+=1;
    }
        else {
            Pi2 -= 1/pow(i,2); 
            i+=1; 
            }
    }

Pi2 *= 12;

cout << Pi2 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

and I have no idea what to write in while() ? When should this loop stop?

Comment: When you want it to stop (i.e. when you've calculated pi to n digits)

Comment: This is a mathematical problem not a programming one. The "error" are the remaining infinite elements you do not compute. 
You can get a bound to that amount and then you know when to stop

Comment: Here is some reading material without solving the homework for you:
http://www.zweigmedia.com/pdfs/TaylorSeries.pdf.. and btw this type of questions belong in math.stackexchange.com/‎

Comment: See this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050980/working-on-code-to-calculate-cosine-with-factorial-sum/22051484#22051484 and write the while to an epsilon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You know the required precision, You can calculate the right value for the maximum value for n before You start the loop.
Second thing: start with the most less number if You start adding all delta values.

Similar to this

```
int ndigits;
cout << "How many digits?" << endl;
cin >> ndigits;
int n = int( pow( double(10), double(ndigits)/2 ) + 0.5 );
long double Pi2 = 0;
int i = 1;

for( int i=n; i>0; --i ) 
{
    if ((i%2) == 1) { 
        Pi2 += 1/pow(long double(i),2); 
    }
    else {
        Pi2 -= 1/pow(long double(i),2); 
    }
}
Pi2 *= 12;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but could you please explain why there's 10^ndig/2+0,5 ? I know it's math problem... but if you could explain it in some simply way I will be greatful :)

Comment: ok, I think I know it already but I have one more question ;) Could you explain why this program has to start from the end - I mean --i? it's something surprising for me. If it's possible to go from beginning, I mean iterations starting from i=1, how this program would look like? I tried to change it to (int i=1; i<n; i++) and it gives a little different calculations. Why? Sorry for stupid questions but I had only 3 classes of c++ ;)

Comment: if You start with i=0, Your first value is 0.5. The sum Pi2 increases to 0.8 and more. 
With big values of i, the offset which will be added becomes very small - e.g. 0.00000001..
The precision of the double or long double is limited, so if adding two numbers of very different scale, the lower one will lose accuracy. Do it one time it isn't a problem - to it many 10000times You lose accuracy in sum.
Changing the order the numbers means that both numbers have a similar scale and don't lose accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

A method to consider is using **ndigits** to create an 'epsilon' value.
Let's assume ndigits is 3.  That give an epsilon of 0.0001

if the difference between your value from the previous iteration, and the current iteration is less than 0.0001, then you can assume you have the value you are after, and terminate the while loop.

A warning though.  Doubles and long doubles have an upper limit on the number of digits they can hold accurately.

Comment: How can i check if the difference between value from previous iteration and the current is less than something? sorry, I know it's easy but i'm trying and i'm getting errors.